# DBT age validation using conditional statement

Tags: dbt, dbtype

Hello I would like to ask for your assistance I'm planning to validate my age field on database however I'm not sure how to make it work on DBT. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

```
  - name: age
    tests:
      - not_null
  #     - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_match_regex:
  #         regex: "[1-9]\\d{3,}"
  #     - dbt_utils.not_empty_string
  #     - dbt_utils.not_constant
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
        expression: "age"
        config:
              where: "age > '110'"
```

[image]

I tried to use this syntax below however its not working and the complied statement showed.

```
  - name: age
    tests:
      - not_null
  #     - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_match_regex:
  #         regex: "[1-9]\\d{3,}"
  #     - dbt_utils.not_empty_string
  #     - dbt_utils.not_constant
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
          expression: '>= 110'
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close!  In dbt tests, you write what you want to *pass* the test and (for this test) then it puts `not(<expression>)` to find the rows that *fail* the test.

Because of that, this should do it:

```yaml
  - name: age
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
          expression: '< 110'
```

Comment: I tried to use this one but the column is not being selected properly

I used this one
      - name: age
        tests:
            - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
                  expression: '< 110'


dbt compiled generated

select
    1
from "testing"."dbt_ralph_rendon"."mrt_user"

where not(age < 110)


my compiled should contain age field not 1

select age
from "testing"."dbt_ralph_rendon"."mrt_user"

where not(age < 110)


For other scenario I'm able to make it work just wondering why the age field suddenly changed by 1 upon using this syntax